# Allow Textfield Inputs to be converted into a button

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, jtextfield

I am currently trying to develop a volunteer app where the administrator can add a volunteer's name into a textfield, and have this input but converted into a new button each time the admin enters a name. I am new to GUI development, so how would I do this? I have tried passing the input as a String into a method, but I am unsure on how to create multiple buttons with this design.

Answer (score 2):

#### Defining UI elements

First to check what you need to implement this quickly.

- You need a panel for your text field and I went for a button to enter current text field input.
- You also need a panel where you are adding your generic buttons
- I also added a list of buttons for convenience, because you likely intend to do something with those buttons later on, and so access is desired

```
// UI elements to type in input and create buttons
private JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel();
private JTextField textField = new JTextField();
private JButton addGenericButtonBtn = new JButton( "ADD NEW BUTTON" );

// UI elements to put your generic buttons into
private JPanel genericButtonsPanel;
private List<JButton> buttonList = new ArrayList<>();
```

#### Creating layouts

You will likely need layouts and button styling, *e.g.* setting sizes for the buttons at least might be necessary, though I will not post that specific code here. The layouts I chose will put your text field and the button to create a generic button horizontally in proximity to one another and the generic buttons will be stacked vertically in the container below:

```
inputPanel.setLayout( new BoxLayout( inputPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS ) );
genericButtonsPanel.setLayout( new BoxLayout( genericButtonsPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS ) );
```

#### Adding your elements to the current hierarchy of UI elements

These pannels must be added to the parent container whichever it is you are working with. Let's say `parentContainer` is a `JPanel` and the one where you want to add all of those elements to:

```
parentContainer.inputPanel.add( textField );
parentContainer.inputPanel.add( addGenericButtonBtn );
parentContainer.add( inputPanel );
parentContainer.add( genericButtonsPanel );
```

#### Adding generic buttons via `ActionListener`

The way this is designed is so that you can type into the text field and then press the "ADD NEW BUTTON" button in order to create generic buttons and add them to the second container `genericButtonsPanel`. So what remains is an action listener for `addGenericButtonsBtn` in order to accomplish this:

```
addGenericButtonBtn.addActionListener( e -> 
{
    String txt = textField.getText();
    JButton genericBtn = new JButton( txt );
    buttonList.add( genericBtn ); // this is merely to store the generated buttons for future access
    genericButtonsPanel.add( genericBtn );
    text.setText( "" ); // optional clear of the text field

    // this call is mandatory, otherwise the changes to the hierarchy of UI elements will not be reflected
    revalidate();
});
```

#### Further reading

This is a very minimalistic example which fulfills the requirements you described. This was just tested on my machine and works as expected. There is also a myriad of ways to go about solving this, so you might see some different solutions.

The presented solution lacks details, such as `setSize`, `setBackground`, `setBorder` and other UI property setters, so you would have to style your UI the way you need it to look yourself.